# Jquery ajax load div content from Web Server to Local Server

Tags: jquery

this code work fine on localhost,when loading div from one blog to another(both on localhost),but when try to load from blog that is on internet to another blog(localhost),it doesn't work,what could be the problem?Here is the code.

```
<?php

$urlPage = 'http://www.somepage.com/'; //dont work

//$urlPage = 'http://localhost/myBlog1/'; //work fine
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var addr;

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        addr = '<?php echo $urlPage; ?>';

        $.ajax( {
            url: addr,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".divToLoadContent").append($(html).find('#sidebar ul').html());
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .divToLoadContent {
        margin:0px;
        border: 1px solid lime;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="divToLoadContent">
</div>
```

Comment: You can't make an AJAX request to a remote domain :)  Not to get raw HTML anyway, JSONP you can though.

Comment: I didnt know that :) tnx,I was just testing on localhost :) I also try on inteternet btw 2 blogs,and still nothing. I'll look now jsonp examples :)

Comment: Still cant get this thing work,can help me with this?I want to pull div tag from one blog to another?

Comment: You can however do a cross-domain ajax like request using this little hack [Using YQL as a proxy for cross-domain Ajax](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy